# Return false; doesn't stop Javascript alert from refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, alert

My code looks a little like this:

```
...
if (reason.options[reason.selectedIndex].value == "0") {
    alert("You must pick a reason for selecting this carrier");
    return false;
}
...
```

I'm checking to see if they left the drop down list untouched (value="0") and if they are, I put up an alert. The return false should stop the alert from refreshing/post back, but it seems to clear everything still. Ideas?

Comment: Is this code within a callback, or when is it called?

Comment: the rest of the code would help? where/why does this happen?

Comment: I don't see any code that refreshes the page in your example.

Comment: There is a lot of the rest of the code. To sum up, the rest in the function posts back, if the drop down has been properly selected. But obviously, I don't want it to post back or refresh at all if it hasn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `return false` will only stop the action if it is the top-level function.

```
element.onclick = function() {return false};
```

That works. This does not:

```
function handle() {return false;}
<a href="somepage.html" onclick="handle()">Click</a>
```

You need to make sure you "pass on" the return value, so something like:

```
<a href="somepage.html" onclick="return handle();">Click</a>
```